# Order of an exponential family possibly less than the dimension of the convex support and parameter space

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

I am going though Brown's book on the Fundamentals of Exponential Families. I am puzzled by the statement that he makes on page 16 where it is possible for

$\text{Order of the exponential family}  < \min\{\text{dim}(\text{aff}(Support)),\text{dim}(\text{aff}(\Theta))\},$

where $\text{aff}(\cdot)$ is the affine hull of a set and $\Theta$ is the parameter space of some exponential family. A similar statement appears in exercise 1.10.1.

It is my understanding that the order of an exponential family is simply the dimension of the canonical parameter or sufficient statistic of a minimal representation of the family. Moreover, in a minimal representation the dimension of the canonical parameter or sufficient statistic equals the dimension of the affine hull of the parameter space and support as otherwise a further reduction of the family is possible. So by definition, for a minimal representation of the family isn't
$\text{Order of the exponential family}  = \text{dim}(\text{aff}(Support)) = \text{dim}(\text{aff}(\Theta))$?

What am I missing here?